# python/pygame: AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'event_get'

Tags: python, pygame

To test my pygame program, I wanted to make a green rectangle move using keyboard inputs,
but when I run it, it crashes with: `AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'event_get'`
Here's the code:

```py
player_x = 50
player_y = 50
display.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(display,green,(player_x,player_y,75,100))
pygame.display.update()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event_get():
      if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
         if(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
             player_x += 10
screen.blit((player_x, payer_y))
pygame.display.update()              

#Exit game
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: It's a typo! It has to be `event.get()` instead of `event_get()`

Answer (score 0):

The [top-level `pygame` package](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#module-pygame) has no `event_get` function. It looks like a typo; change the call in the first loop from `pygame.event_get()` to [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get), changing the underscore to a dot, matching the second loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).